# using hibernate, how to write @OneToMany(mappedBy="somethingFkId") in xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

does anyone know how to write `@OneToMany(mappedBy="customers")` in xml?

I searched everywhere but didn't find anyone who write mappedBy in xml. I need to map one-to-many that mappedBy other column in other existing entity without creating new entity(like join table) or new collumn. I don't have the right to add another column or table. I know the way to do it is using hibernate anotation `@OneToMany(mappedBy="customers")`.

But how to write it in xml? because my other project use java 1.4 that doesn't support annotation, so i can't use that `@OneToMany(mappedBy="customers")`.

Something like this in java 1.6 :

in table B:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="bId", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
private Set<AJoinB> testJoins = new HashSet<AJoinB>();
```

in table AJoinB :

```
@Column(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
private Long bId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is an example of using one-to-many tag in xml http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: mappedBy and joinColumn not only relating one-to-many relationship but also how you define the owner of the relationship, is this xml already define that inside?

Comment: Yes, it defines the owner side with inverse parameter. inverse=true if the relationship is owner and false in other case.

Answer (score 1):

this is the example of one to many :

```
   <set name="stockDailyRecords" table="stock_daily_record" 
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.mkyong.stock.StockDailyRecord" />
    </set>
```

the **inverse** will wark wich one is the owner

Answer (score 0):

Here's and example I have in my code a Utility can have many Accounts

The first declaration is in the Account.hbm.xml config and the second is in my Utility.hbm.xml

```
    <many-to-one name="utility" class="com.entity.Utility" fetch="select" lazy="false">
        <column name="utility_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>


    <property name="utility_id" not-null="true">
        <column name="utility_id" />
    </property>
```

*Note I have this declared in both my java files and hibernate files, just because that's how I initially was taught this. So I'm not 100% sure if this standalone capable.

Answer (score 0):

The "one-to-many" element has a "mapped-by" attribute which can be used as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <package>com.chiranth.bean</package>
    <entity class="Person" >
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <column name="sl_no" />
                <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
            </id>
            <basic name="name" />
            <basic name="place" />
            <basic name="age" />
            <basic name="dateOfBirth">
                <column name="birthdate" />
            </basic>
            <one-to-many name="cars" mapped-by="person"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```